# React Service worker: Load new content without forcing user to close the tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker, web-worker

I'm working on implementing the service worker concept in react and I have added all the configurations suggested in the Link [making-a-progressive-web-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/) but the problem here is that for displaying the new content (when the network changed from offline to online), I've to display user to message like 'New content is available once existing tabs are closed.' So here we're forcing the user to close the page for displaying new content. Even the refresh option is also not working here.

Check the below method - (This is a method created when we build react app using create-react-app, the method can be found in react-app/service-worker.js)

```
function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed. See'
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}
```

You can clearly see the console

> New content is available and will be used when all tabs for this page are closed.

What is the best way to achieve this? So only refreshing the page, we can update the previous stored cache.

Comment: Personally, [in my app](https://github.com/moshfeu/synced-shopping-list/blob/2ecaf62673f0d2bd3ed8732f48a55242b95629fb/src/index.tsx#L39-L44), I chosen to refresh the app without asking the user. But `location.reload()` should do the job anyway.

Comment: did you get this working? I am facing same problem.

Comment: `location.reload()` does not work. That only refreshes the page, it does not refresh the service worker.

Answer (score 0):

hi I had the same problem while working with PWA you can the following code in the where ever you have registered the service-worker

```
serviceWorker.register({
    onUpdate: registration => {
    alert('New version available!  Ready to update?');
    window.location.reload();
      if (registration && registration.waiting) {
        registration.waiting.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
      }
    }
  });
```